# Base map layer for Here XYZ Studio

Tags: here-maps-rest

We would like to use a Here map style to create a base map layer in Studio XYZ and the Studio playground.

All of the examples and documentation we have found use mapcreator.tilehub.api.here.com/tilehub/wv_livemap_bc/png/sat/256/ to display a Satellite map layer.

We would like to use the map styles available when calling http://image.maps.api.here.com/mia/1.6/ for example Road, NormalDay, Hybrid, etc.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the '**sat**' in mapcreator.tilehub.api.here.com/tilehub/wv_livemap_bc/png/**sat**/256/ with '**normal.day**' to get a normal day map. 
check more on [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/map-types.html)